# Automatic word wrap in Mousepad

Tags: mousepad

How to enable automatic word wrap for **every text document** opened with Mousepad?

Every time I create a new document word wrapping is disabled by default. Also, selecting word wrap in the Document menu only works for the current document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add automatic wrapping to the global configuration of Mousepad, add the following line to `~/.config/Mousepad/mousepadrc`:

```
ViewWordWrap=true
```

(In my case, I had to create that configuration file.)

Source: [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179514).

Comment: According to the source, it works by deleting the folder